# MySQL How many distinct values are there in a column and what the # of occurences of each one of them?

Tags: mysql

As the titles say. I am already able to calculate the DISTINCT values in a column, but not sure how to calculate their occurences so that I get a one line code that answers both questions at the same time.

I have solved this by two queries:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT GovernmentForm) FROM country;

SELECT GovernmentForm, COUNT(*) FROM country GROUP BY GovernmentForm;

But I want to write a code that solves both questions in one query.

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you:

```
SELECT t.fieldname , sum(1) as occurences
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.fieldname;
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` would be more usual.

Comment: @user207421 - look at the source code for COUNT(*) and SUM(1) and answer again